# Sensor to focus a robot on a welding line. (PLC robotics)

Tags: sensor, robotics, plc

I'm searching for a way to recognize a welding line in an area. When the line is recognized, a small robot needs to follow the line.

I searched the web already and spoke with some sensor suppliers. Until now nobody could give me a proper solution for this.

My first tough was to go with a vision camera to see if there is enough color difference between the weld and the surounding area. (I don't have experience with those vision camera/ sensors) Is this possible? Is there a better/easier/cheaper way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1.
First of all thanks for responding.

The weld locates it self in a large area (square of 40x40 meters.) The weld connects two sheets of steel which form the area. The area it self is quite dark as it is inside without a lot of illumination.

The sensor can be place from a few millimeters upto 200 millitmeters from the weld.  The weld is 20 millimeters wide.

The weld line is not raised as two sheets lay on top of eachother and welded on the side.

The machine should remove the weld. So temperature can't be used to track it.

Comment: What is the geometry of the pieces being welded? If you're examining seams in flat sheet then "dark field" lighting (low-angle from side with overhead camera) might work well. In vision applications lighting will be hugely significant in the success of the project. We'd need a lot more information.

Comment: Also need to know how close the sensor will be to the weld line, height of the weld line, width of the weld line, etc. Things like infrared time-of-flight might work, or LIDAR, depending on the resolution needed and distance from the weld.

Comment: if the weld line is raised, then some type of a capacitive sensor may work

Comment: How long after the welding process? You could use the fact the weld is still hot...

Comment: You need some simple machine vision. My company does such systems, it is easy but takes some expertise.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still unclear.

[image]

*Figure 1. Edge detection using inductive or optical sensors.*

If they are overlapped as shown in Figure 1 then it may be possible to trace out the edge using the robot with a couple of sensors in much the same way as is done on line-following robot toys / projects. The main programming challenge would be to accommodate the offset between the sensors and the following cutter. Also, be aware that proximity sensors can interfere with each other and for close proximity mounting certain types would be required. This might be enough to make optical a better solution (although dust may be a problem with these).

[image]

*Figure 2. Simple overlay.*

If the weld is on the edges the approach of Figure 1 would work again (if ever) but machine vision would be much simpler with lighting being less critical.

Comment: Hi, it is indeed figure 1. I will search for an optical solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use a laser profiler.

[image: adhesive bead inspection]
img source: [Cognex](https://www.cognex.com/industries/automotive/safety-systems/windshield-glue-bead-installation)

They are commonly used in electronics manufacturing to ensure that components have been placed properly and in the auto industry to inspect adhesive or weld beads. One could give you a wider inspection range than discrete sensors and make the application less reliant on perfect lighting.

I'm most familiar with the [Keyence](https://www.keyence.com/products/measure/laser-2d/lj-x8000/index_pr.jsp) version but several manufacturers make them (Cognex, Omron, Gocator etc).

With one of these mounted on a robot, you should be able to monitor the weld as the robot moves and adjust your path accordingly. If you want to get fancy, these are usually capable of scanning an entire surface and presenting a 3D map for analysis.